# proto.menu event handler for a button created after the menu

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

This is going to take more experienced javascript brains than mine, I think.

We make use of proto.menu and it works really well for providing dropdown menus when the button is drawn as an inline part of the page; the proto.menu binding happens as a part of the dom:loaded event. We have a situation where a button is loaded, removed, and reloaded using server-side logic, based on information from the page *after* the page is loaded.

Page loads...

User changes a piece of data and saves.

Post-save, the button, #btnWarranty, is added to the DOM.

{And now, what I want:>>}The button's click event is bound to the menu object created by proto.menu

The button, and :

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <div class="toolbarButton" id="btnWarranty">Warranty Options</div>
</div>
```

The menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vmnuWarranty = [
{
    name: 'MBPI&nbsp;<i>Extra</i>&raquo;'
    , callback: function(){
    dealWorksheet.showMBPIForm(5330, 'extra');
    }
} 
, {
    name: 'ASC'
    , callback: function(){
    dealWorksheet.showASCForm(5330);
    }
}
]

Event.observe(document, "dom:loaded", function(){
    new Proto.Menu({
        selector: '#btnWarranty'
        , className: 'menu desktop'
        , menuItems: vmnuWarranty
        , useTargetPos: 'sw'
        , activator: 'click'
        , menuid: 'mnuWarranty'
    })
});

</script>
```

Can someone familiar with proto.menu tell me how to show one of its menus when the calling object is built after the fact?

Comment: Why not create the `new Proto.Menu` instance when you are adding the buttons to the DOM (instead of on-dom:loaded)?

Comment: @Bergi The Proto.Menu is created as a part of the engine that generates the page. Also, there's no guarantee that each instance of the same menu would be discrete. It is conceivable that a user could sit on the page, making changes and saving over and over and over. The page could end up with a dozen instances of the menu.

Comment: I found the answer myself, or at least an answer that works.  

The code given in all Proto.Menu examples reads `new Proto.Menu({`. By assigning this to a variable, as in `var myMenu = new Proto.menu({` one can now reference the .show() method of the object, and thus no further binding is needed.